# Tornar opaca/escurecer uma foto em background. Devo usar pseudo elemento ::after?

Tags: html, css, background, opacity, pseudo-elementos

Preciso escurecer/ou tornar opaca uma foto usada em background no header do html. Tentei usar um ::after em position relative aplicando um rgba, mas nao esta dando certo. Qual solucao eu poderia dar neste caso?
Eu coloquei a classe diretamente no header do html.
E a imagem na class header (css)
Desde jah agradeco!!

```
<header class="header">
<div class="container">
  <a class="header-logo grid-4" href="#">
    <img class="" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <nav class="header-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Immersive <br> experiences <br> that deliver</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background: url("../images/desktop/image-hero.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

[image: header]

Comment: Já tentou com `filter: brightness(50%);`? Documentação [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso não precisa necessariamente de *pseudo-element* vc pode simplesmente adicionar dois `backgrounds` no mesmo elemento, um com a imagem, e por cima da imagem um `linear-gradiente` (o gradiente nesse caso vai ter como início e fim a mesma cor).

Para usar dois `background` no mesmo elemento basta separa-los por vírgula, tipo

```
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(https://unsplash.it/200/180);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código completo com o exemplo, fiz um com um gradiente escuro por cima da imagem usando cor `rgba()`, e outro com um gradiente branco.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  display: inline-block;

  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(https://unsplash.it/200/180);
}

.box + .box {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(255,255,255,0.5)),
    url(https://unsplash.it/200/181);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**OBS:** Se vc quiser tetar umas "doideras" fazendo sobreposição de imagens ou gradientes multi-coloridos vc ainda pobe brincar com a propriedade `background-blend-mode`. Aqui tem um playground para vc ver em ação: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-blend-mode

Comment: Hugo, deu certo!  Obrigado por responder!  Abs

Comment: @GeorgeGalli sem problemas meu caro, fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira bem prática, assim como no comentário do **Augusto Vasques**, seria com o filter:

```css
#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiAZV.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.25) opacity(0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="background"><div/>
```

Mas se tratando de `CSS`, sempre existem várias maneiras, conforme sua necessidade.

Vale dizer que no caso de ser uma imagem estática, como o plano de fundo ou um banner, você poderia utilizar a imagem pronta (com `.png`, você consegue manter a transparência da imagem, por exemplo, bastando procurar um editor online ou até um aplicativo gratuito como o Photoscape ou pago, como o Photoshop).